# Oracle query optimization written on table with partition

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning, analytic-functions

I have one table in Oracle consists of around 55 million records with **partition on date column.**

This table stores around 600,000 records for each day based on some position.

Now, some analytical functions are used in one select query in procedure e.g. lead, lag, row_number() over(partition by col1, **date** order by col1, **date**) which is taking too much time due to 'partition by' and 'order by' clause on date column.

Is there any other alternative to optimize the query ?

Comment: You are making an assumption as to why it's taking too long.  Have you captured an extended SQL trace using `DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE`?  What's the execution plan?

Comment: If I comment the column using analytical function in select query then it runs very fast

Comment: It runs very fast, or it starts returning data very fast?  There's a difference.  Adding an analytic function requires Oracle to partition the data and sort it all within those before it can start assigning the row_numbers() - and returning data to you.  What's the ENTIRE query?

Comment: Hi Adam, can you give ur email id

Comment: @user1017936, you can edit your question to add the query. Just use the `edit` buttom at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @user1017936:  No, I'm not providing my email address.  Not without a consulting contract.

Comment: This may be neither here nor there, but if your analytic function already partitions by `COL1` and `DATE`, then `ORDER`ing `BY` `COL1` and `DATE` makes no sense:  there'll be no sensible differentiation within the analytic-function partition to order by.  You might as well `PARTITION BY col1, date ORDER BY NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a materialized view where you store the results of your analytical functions?

More information about MVs

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm